# Generate a horizontal rule accross generated pdf

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf-generation, itext

I am populating a pdf with text using the code below. Is it possible to add a line? or horizontal rule accross the pdf so I split the text into sections?

```
Session("PDF") = Session("Hospital") + Environment.NewLine + Session("HospitalAddress") + Environment.NewLine + Session("HospitalCity")

Dim myUniqueFileName = String.Format("{0}.pdf", random)
    Dim pdfWrite As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc1, New FileStream(path & myUniqueFileName, FileMode.Create))

    Doc1.Open()
    Dim test As String
    test = Session("PDF")
    Dim imagepath As String = Server.MapPath(".") & "/images/Header.png"
    Dim image As iTextSharp.text.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagepath)
    image.ScalePercent(70.0F)

    Doc1.Add(image)
    Doc1.Add(New Paragraph(test))

    Doc1.Close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to draw the horizontal line like this:

```
Dim cb As PdfContentByte = pdfWrite.DirectContent

' Set thickness to 2.0, rather than 1.0 default
cb.SetLineWidth(2F)

' 1.0 = black; 0.0 = white
cb.SetGrayStroke(0.95F)

' Set x and y coordinates for points of line to draw between, numbers made up for this example
cb.MoveTo(25, 50)
cb.LineTo(400, 50)
cb.Stroke()
```

Comment: Thanks, right now the line is on the bottom of the page. Which number do I change to move it up?

Comment: The second value is the y value. `Doc1.Top` will put you at the top of the page so you will need to subtract whatever spacing to move it around.